# Read to right of specific symbol in file from Python

Tags: python, file, string

I'm going to separate over 1000 virus signatures and the virus names. I have them all in a text file, and would like to do this with python.

**Here is the format:**

```
virus=signature
```

I need to be able to take 'virus' and write it to one file, then take 'signature' and write it to another.

---

**This is what I've tied so far**:

```
h = open("FILEWITHSIGS")
j = h.read()
k = h.split('=')
```

And that is basically where I got stuck. No matter what I tried, it printed (or writed) both to the same place.

Comment: You opened only one file and expect to write to two places? What kind of logic is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f1=open("first.txt","a")
f2=open("second.txt","a")
for line in open("file"):
    s=line.split("=",1)
    f1.write(s[0]+"\n")
    f2.write(s[-1])
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: What if the signature contained an '='..? Sorry SilentGhost is getting my 1UP.

Answer (score 4):

```
with open(fname) as inputf, open(virf, 'w') as viruses, open(sigs, 'w') as signatures:
    for line in inputf:
        virus, _, sig = line.partition('=')
        viruses.write(virus + '\n')
        signatures.write(sig)
```